# show rows into dynamic columns way

Tags: sql-server

dears ,

i have below data into table my_temp as below and  need to show it like calendar .

table :my_temp

```
date        time    id
2018-08-04  01:00   9935
2018-09-04  09:00   9935
2018-09-05  01:00   9944
2018-09-05  04:00   7228
2018-09-08  09:00   7247
```

need to show it like below (change rows to be columns for the date column , and this column should be dynamic ).

```
2018-08-04                    2018-09-05                2018-09-08  
id : 9935 , time : 01:00     id : 9944 ,time :9944     id : 7247,time: 09:00
id : 9935 , time : 09:00     id :7228,time :04:00
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review the [ask] section and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I think this demo could help you out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0r__N4OEVs

Comment: I think this is more suited for a presentation layer, like SSRS.

Comment: SQL Server is used to (and used to) create relational results (something that has a fix set of columns and multiple rows) that have one value per row/column. Your desired result looks more like a user interface.